# Keyboard event does not scroll the scrollbar of dropdown

Tags: html, css, angular, dropdown

I have made code like below

https://plnkr.co/edit/LG8cOx?p=preview

```
 eventHandler(event) {
}
```

Above is the funstion handling keyboard events in code.

I have given keyboard events to select the elements. It works fine. Earlier i did not have scrollbar on dropdown list. Now that i have the scrolbar, when i scroll beyond what is visible, the scrollbar does not move. Is there anyway to enable scrolling using keyboard events?

Answer (score 0):

I have created this [working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/WaF402?p=preview) taking the code reference from `md-autocomplete` scroll list.

Just like we manually handle of highlighting the options on key up and down, scroll needs to be handled manually too. Please adjust the height of `li`, `dropdown` panel, `OPTION_HEIGHT` and `PANEL_HEIGHT` to your requirement.

Here, I am adding only new code needed to get the scroll working. All new lines in plunker are clearly marked with comments.

component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('panel') panel: ElementRef;

const OPTION_HEIGHT = 36;

const PANEL_HEIGHT = 96;  

eventHandler(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.SearchDropDown = true;
        if(this.focusedIdx >= -1 && (this.focusedIdx < this.mockdata.length)){
          this.focusedIdx++;
          this._scrollToOption(this.focusedIdx);
        }
        else{
          this.focusedIdx = 0;  
          this._scrollToOption(this.focusedIdx);
        }
    }
    if (event.key == "ArrowUp") {
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.SearchDropDown = true;

        if(this.focusedIdx > -1 && (this.focusedIdx != 0)){
          this.focusedIdx--;
          this._scrollToOption(this.focusedIdx);
        }
        else{
          this.focusedIdx = this.mockdata.length - 1;
          this._scrollToOption(this.focusedIdx);
        }
    }

    if (event.code == "Enter" && this.focusedIdx > -1){
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.selectDropdown(this.mockdata[this.focusedIdx]); 
    }
}

_getScrollTop(): number {
  let x = this.panel.nativeElement.scrollTop;
  return x;
}

_setScrollTop(scrollTop: number): void {
  console.log("St: " + this.scrollTop);
  if (this.panel) {
    this.panel.nativeElement.scrollTop = scrollTop;
  }
}

private _scrollToOption(activeItemIndex): void {
  const optionOffset = activeItemIndex * this.OPTION_HEIGHT : 0;
  const panelTop = this._getScrollTop();

  if (optionOffset < panelTop) {
    this._setScrollTop(optionOffset);
      } else if (optionOffset + this.OPTION_HEIGHT > panelTop + this.PANEL_HEIGHT) {
    // Scroll down to reveal selected option scrolled below the panel bottom
    const newScrollTop =
        Math.max(0, optionOffset - this.PANEL_HEIGHT + this.OPTION_HEIGHT);
        this._setScrollTop(newScrollTop);
  }
}
```

html:

```
 <!-- ADD #panel here -->
 <ul class="chosen-results custom-selectbox-list-cont customized-dropDown-active nav" #panel>
 </ul>
```

css:

```
li {
  min-height: 24px;  /* Adjust height here */
}
```